# How do I mimic the Publish button in Visual Studio from within the .csproj file?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2013 web application project and I have a Local File System publish profile setup for it.  When I right click on the project in Visual Studio and choose "Publish" I can publish just fine and everything behaves as expected.  However, I need this publish to occur automatically on build because other projects in the solution depend on this project being deployed locally.  In my case, the deploy goes into a `$(ProjectDir)/Deploy` folder.

How can I make it so when I build this project using `msbuild myproject.csproj` or right click Build, the project will be deployed per the .pubxml file?

Answer (score 0):

What ended up being the solution was adding this to the end of my `.csproj` file.

```
<Target Name="Deploy" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild
        Projects="$(ProjectPath)"
        Targets="WebPublish"
        Properties="PublishProfile=LocalDeploy"
    />
</Target>
```

`LocalDeploy` is the name of my `.pubxml` file found in `$(ProjectDir)Properties/PublishProfiles`.

For reference, here is the publish profile being used:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Debug</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>True</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\Deploy</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```